# infer the initial state from draws

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

I went through binomial distribution and Chi-square test etc and got confused further. This question might be very basic and simple.

I have three states (Combination of two colors, both has equal chance) which are hidden (RedRed , RedBlue, BlueBlue) and each draw gives either Red or Blue. Red and Blue are independent. Now from N draws, I want to infer the likelihood of states with a given probability.

Example 1:
n =20 ; Observed Red =12 & Blue= 10 then I want to find the likelihood of having  RedRed , RedBlue & BlueBlue states. I guess it will be something like 0, 1, 0 respectively in this case.

But often n is small
Example 2:
n =4 ; Observed Red =1 & Blue= 3, Now how likely its BlueBlue, RedBlue & RedRed(unlikely )?.

I will really appreciate your answers. It wold be great if you comment any R function with this examples.

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Here's MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have two states, this is just a binomial prediction problem.

A common approach is to use a [Beta-Binomial model](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/lecture/technote2_betabinomial.pdf),which allows you to specify the "prior" probabilities of different proportions of Blue vs Red and then use your sample to adjust this based on your observations. In fact, this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_as_an_urn_model) article shows how this can be applied to your exact situation.

If you don't like Bayesian approaches, then you can also use a "prior free" likelihood-based approach. A simple prediction formula is given by [Hinkley](http://books.google.com/books?id=8T8fAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=hinkley%20binomial%20predictive%20likelihood&source=bl&ots=LHM00Gqgba&sig=YBWSpgYetvfQhWm2X9YWg7xvamY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GFHaU-ywK4njsASujoKACw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hinkley%20binomial%20predictive%20likelihood&f=false).